# Chart.js not showing up on online site

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I really can't figure this  out.

I'm using Chart.js - and the chart works fine local but when I try to show it online on my server it doesn't work.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Udvikling i motorvejstrafikken 2010-2017',
            data: [100, 103.5, 107.2, 110.3, 115.4, 120.9, 126.3, 131.5],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 4
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    min: 90
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
```

When I check the console in chrome I get this error:`tester:890 Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
    at tester:890`

I check in sources and it says that there is an error here:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
```

But what is causing this problem. Works fine local and on fiddle.net.

Hopefully somebody is able to help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you define your script at the top or the bottom (can't tell with a snippet). Because I once had the problem that I had my script tags at the bottom and local it worked but when I tried putting it online it didn't. When I put the script tags at the beginning it worked fine for me. Or does your server not allow your sources to be pulled from the internet? try downloading the scripts and put them online with your chart. Because to me it seems the error refers that your scripts are not correct because it doesn't recognize the Chart method.

Comment: Seem you javascript file - where you write `new Chart(ctx, {` is on top of char.js file

Comment: I define my scripts at the top of my file.
Normally we are allowed to get scripts from the internet, but  I will try to download the scripts. Thanks.

Comment: I tried downloading the scripts and put in online with my file. But that **didn't work** either.

Comment: @WhiteHat - No i'm not. :(

Comment: @WhiteHat - No this is it..

Answer (score 2):

Bit late but I had the same problem. To fix it you need to get your chart to generate from window.onload.

e.g.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"],
          datasets: [{
              label: 'Udvikling i motorvejstrafikken 2010-2017',
              data: [100, 103.5, 107.2, 110.3, 115.4, 120.9, 126.3, 131.5],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 4
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      min: 90
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
  });
};
```

Don't know why it works locally without this, but needed this change to display on the server.